# xamarin.essentials.connectivity.NetworkAccess

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.essentials

There is a way to set the **NetworkAccess** (or the **PlatformNetworkAccess**) prop to some value by reflection?

[Nuget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGeTM.png)

Comment: why do you want to do this, or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I wanna create unit test for ViewModels but these VMs inherit from a class that use the NetworkAccess property in the constructor. It means that my tests fail every time I create a new instance of the VMs

Comment: https://evgenyzborovsky.com/2019/01/09/mocking-xamarin-essentials/

Comment: The problem is that the nuget I use (from I inherit BaseWM) is out from my namespace, I cant change logic there.

Comment: With little info on the structure or what youre dealing with we cant make alternative suggestions cause if youre having to do reflection youre going down the wrong path